# How to avoid "org.testng.TestNGException: The test(s) <[a-t1,a-t3]> cannot be found."?

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin, testng.xml

When running an testng xml, it runs only the specified tests (i.e., a-t1,a-t3 from below example).

Refer 'Running 'testnames' in test tag' section in https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html for more information.

```
</plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
          [...]
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <file>src/test/resources/suite.xml</file>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>testnames</name>
              <value>a-t1,a-t3</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
          [...]
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

When running a single test from Eclipse with these tags, getting below exception.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
The test(s) <[a-t1,a-t3]> cannot be found.
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:315)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:350)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:980)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:98)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

To avoid the above exception, I should have to comment out properties tags of surefire plugin.

**Is there anyway to avoid the exception without having to comment out the properties tags of surefire plugin?**

```
<properties>
  <property>
    <name>testnames</name>
    <value>a-t1,a-t3</value>
  </property>
</properties>
```

Comment: Why do you want to include `testnames` property under `surefire` plugin ? Why not just run tests from `testng.xml`

Comment: I have a requirement to run a single test from Jenkins, so using 'testnames' property.

Comment: use this `<classes>
    <class name="yourClass">
      <methods>
        <include name="testmethod" />
      </methods>
    </class>
  </classes>` to run single test from testng.xml

Comment: Here, Single test means single test tag in testng xml, not single method.

Comment: Yes , you can put that in a test tag and run that tag from jenkins by passing `-testnames` command line arguments. `Only tests defined in a <test> tag matching one of these names will be run.` from official tetsng site

Answer (score 0):

```
try running without suiteXml tags as follow:

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
<!--                    <suiteXmlFiles> -->
<!--                        <file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</file> -->
<!--                    </suiteXmlFiles> -->
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>testnames</name>
                            <value>surefirePlugin.TestmyMethod,surefirePlugin.TestmyMethod1</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Commenting out suiteXmlFiles tag doesn't work for me. Is there any other way to avoid the issue without having to comment out suiteXmlFiles tag?